# Spring Batch recommended

Tags: spring-batch

I have to design a web page which selects and exports a bunch of XML to the browser as a zip file (synchronously). Is spring batch recommended for this? or any other feature of Spring will come handy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring batch is a framework for running batch processes and takes care of some common batch processing related concerns like scheduling, reruns etc. 

There is nothing in Spring that specifically solves your problem

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I just wanted to assert that.

Answer (score 3):

The conversion part *could* be done with Spring Batch, but it would be like swatting a fly with a buick. And running a spring batch job synchronously in a browser request is theoretically possible, but far from being a good practice.